# POST JSON *in Request Body* using MooTools

Tags: javascript, json, post, mootools

I'm trying to post JSON between URLs in my app. The receiving URL expects JSON in the body of the request and responds with JSON in the body of the request. The problem is I can't seem to send JSON in the body using Mootools Request.JSON. This is what I have:

```
// formObj is an object constructed from a form
var request = new Request.JSON({
    url: "/api/object.new",
    urlEncoded: false,
    onRequest: function(){
        // swap submit button with spinner
    },
    onComplete: function(jsonObj) {
        // work with returned JSON
    },
    body: JSON.encode(formObj)
});
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.post();
```

The server returns a 500 error:

```
BadValueError: Property name is required
```

Which means that `request.name` is returning `None` which means that the server is not getting my JSON.

Using [HTTPClient](http://ditchnet.org/httpclient/) to paste the output of JSON.encode(formObj) into the body field produces the desired results.

Comment: try,
body:"x=" + JSON.encode(obj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

body is not a valid mootools property for Request. use `data: blah` instead. as it stands, data is empty so no wonder you get nothing on the server side...

Comment: For whatever reason `data` didn't work before, perhaps I messed something else up but I drew the conclusion that `data` wasn't equivalent to 'body'. Sorry, for asking a dumb question.

Comment: This 'solution' does not post JSON, but just sends a standard POST request.

Comment: `Request.JSON` does not post JSON, it expects to receive JSON in return, the request could be a simple GET.